# What is the alternative to using id or a pointer to a class name as the return type of a class method that will return a "typed" value?

Tags: objective-c

When returning an object from a class method in objective-c, I understand there is a result type one can use instead of id to return the a "typed" value. What is that result type?

Assume a class method like `+ (id)sharedInstance`. What can be used in place of `id`, besides the class that will return a "typed" instance of the class?

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
+ (something_other_than_id_or_SomeClass)sharedInstance;
@end
```

Comment: Curious to know, why this might be considered a bad, poor, or undesirable question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;
```

Comment: ... and this is the documentation: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#objective-c-features

Comment: @Paul.s That's what I was looking for. Any comment on the benefits and drawbacks of using `instancetype` versus `id`?

Comment: @Paul.s funny, I believe that is where I first saw it. Thank you.